# What does it mean to prove statements or solve problems "from first principles"?

Tags: terminology, axioms

When asked to solve or prove something from first principles, what do they mean by that? They expect you to use only axioms or basic properties or both or it can be a bit more subjective understanding of the term?

Comment: Specifically, which area of math are you talking about? Calculus?

Comment: It's normally axioms and definitions. Calculating a derivative from first principles, for example, would involve doing it directly from the definition of the derivative rather than the chain rule, product rule, etc.

Comment: That is my main question. Sometimes I think it depends on the area, but if they ask for "first principles" I would expect to have an unambigous meaning of that term.

Comment: "First principles" is always local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got the intuition right. First principle implies you use the fundamental definitions, properties or axioms for the problem at hand. For example, If you are asked to find the derivative of $\tan(x)$ from first principles, you would do
something like this:

$
\frac{d}{dx}\big(\tan(x)\big)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \bigg(\frac{\tan(x+h)-\tan(x)}{h}\bigg)
$

You could use $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and apply the quotient rule but that would not be considered first principles. You are not using basic definition but a rule/property that is a consequence of the main definition.

Similarly in integrating $f(x)=x^{2}$ doing it from first principles implies using the Riemann integration and showing that it converges and finding the value.

I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 1):

First principals are basic, evident assumptions that we begin with whenever we seek to start proving stuff. Their fairly similar to axioms, but I like to think as axioms as being a *minimal* set of assumptions, whereas your first principals include all other *obvious* facts too.

Proving something "from first principles" contrasts with, what I've heard some people refer to as, *driving in a nail with a sledgehammer*. It can certainly make your problem easy to solve, but sometimes it doesn't feel very elegant, especially if your problem shouldn't be too tough to solve. So sometimes instructors will ask that you prove a statement "from first principles" to see that you can come up with the elegant argument. A common example of this is the use of [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) to evaluate certain limits. L'Hôpital's is a sledgehammer: it's not immediately obvious why L'Hôpital's rule works, and [its proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule#Proof_of_L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) isn't straightforward. Using L'Hôpital's rule to analyze an otherwise easy-to-evaluate limit seems inappropriate.